# On Android, can Crashlytics "see" crashes that happen in a service?

Tags: android, android-service, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm new to Crashlytics and I'm just testing it by throwing exceptions in parts of my app.

If I throw an exception from a button click in an activity, I get a report.

If I throw a RuntimeException in

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent)  { ... }
```

inside an IntentService, Crashlytics doesn't seem to catch that.

Question: What do I have to do to get reports from crashes in a service?
Brownie points for telling me more about Crashlytics reporting things from threads other than the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I'm not sure if this is needed for services but reporting manually can be done like this:

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here! 
}
```

see [Crashlytics knowledge base](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions)

Also Crashlytics installs an UncaughtExceptionHandler which should catch errors on all threads unless they are handled/discarded/logged by some internal android component.